# Как опубликовать расширение google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Официальная документация google по публикации расширения несколько сумбурная - то надо сделать *.crx файл, то для публикации уже надо упаковать все в zip архив (при этом не ясно зачем нам *.crx). Надо ли прописывать в manifesto параметры для автообновления расширения, можно ли сохранить файлы на google-drive (ссылки на файлы сохраняются без расширения и имени файла) и будет ли происходить обновление с google-drive по таким ссылкам?
    Просьба подсказать пошаговую инструкцию на публикацию расширения в google chrome с уточнениями по вышеописанным моментам.

Answer (score 0):

Упаковать расширение надо в Google Chrome в разделе "Управление расширениями". Обновление происходит в личном кабинете разработчика, просто заливаете новую версию. Так же надо сделать иконки разных размеров. +придется заплатить 5$ за аккаунт разработчика Google Chrome

Comment: Никита, это не то. У меня конкретные вопросы выше, которые требуют ответа более чем 3 предложения